# DAX - calculation of 3-month rolling average for a specific working day

Tags: powerbi, dax, rolling-average

I have a table with a lot of dimensions, month, working day and amount.
I would like to create a measure in PowerBI, which calculates the average of last 3 months for that particular working day.
I can create similar in SQL using AVG OVER (PARTION BY) but I would like to have it as a dynamic measure which changes when user filters on the different dimensions.

[example table, if I see total work day 5 I should get average of 49.3 (= sum of 148 / 3 months)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvoMF.png)

Many thanks and let me know if any further information is needed.

I am a beginner in DAX and I could not find a similar problem online. I can solve it in SQL but then I need a dynamic measure in PBI.

Edit:
Hi, Sam Nseir, thank you for the help.
In first solution, if I remove the divide by 3 I get the same numbers as current work day.
Same in the second solution.

Below is the result, when I filter on work day 8 in my report.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylcO6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Measure similar to this one:

```
RAvg 3-Month = 
  AVERAGEX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[Working Day]),
    CALCULATE(
      AVERAGEX(
        DISTINCT('YourTable'[Month]),
        CALCULATE(SUM('YourTable'[Amount]))
      ),
      DATESINPERIOD('YourTable'[Month], MAX('YourTable'[Month]), -3, MONTH)
    )
  )
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The formula provides some metrics, however they seem to be much lower than they should. Around 3 times lower, but not exactly.

Comment: The expression given above is as you wanted in your question. Update your question above with example data and values you are getting vs values you are expecting. I've also added another version that you could try in the answer above.

Comment: I have updated my main post.

Comment: Try the updated answer above.

Comment: Super, please help mark the answer as [Accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97kjx.png) for the benefit of all.

Answer (score 0):

What if you return return m3amt instead of DIVIDE(m3amt, 3)?

```
RAvg 3-Month = 
  AVERAGEX(
    DISTINCT('YourTable'[WorkingDay]),
    (
      var m3amt = 
        CALCULATE(
          SUM('YourTable'[Amount]),
          DATESINPERIOD('YourTable'[Month], MAX('YourTable'[Month]), -2, MONTH)
        )
      return m3amt
    )
  )
```

Comment: Then I just get the amount for that working day.